# Setting up Kong and Keycloak with Reverse Proxy

Tags: api, nginx, keycloak, reverse-proxy, kong

I am trying to secure an API using Kong as API Gateway, Keycloak as IAM service and NGINX as reverse proxy all of which are up within containers. Kong and Keycloak are connected to each other via OIDC plugin. The desired scenario is the following;

When a client makes request NGINX will redirect the request to Kong and if the client is not logged in it will be redirected to Keycloak’s login page to be redirected to Kong again after a successful login. Most of the flow is working except when the client is redirected to Keycloak, Keycloak’s 8080 port is not hidden, same for the Kong’s 8000 port once the user makes a successful login and redirected back to Kong. We tried a couple of solutions but they did not work out. What is the correct way to set these up to hide their ports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not requesting nginx or keycloak, but url. I recommend to have all traffic through Kong, but the right url configuration (no port, just kong url) and kong doing the reverse proxy hiding port.
Can you share what you have tried and which error you get ?

Comment: @Ôrel 
Hi, I tried putting both Kong and Keycloak behind NGINX Reverse Proxy to hide their ports but they both gave an error. I would like to try your suggestion, to put them behind Kong and eliminate NGINX (if I understood correctly). What plugin or method should I use with Kong for that? There seems to be no default way of hiding the port with Kong, or most probably that I could find.

Comment: I don't understand what you call hiding Kong port, if kong is your exposed solution you need to know the port

Comment: Hi @Örel . This is my other account. What I actually  want is; sending a request to our remote server which the API resides behind Kong (e.g. h ttp://remoteIP/my_app). How can I achieve this with Kong without using NGINX with reverse proxy?

Comment: Kong is built on top of nginx so you can easily reproduce your nginx conf

Comment: I put Keycloak behind Kong and it seems to work fine without OIDC plugin. As soon as the OIDC is activated Kong starts giving errors.